# Checking whether the minimal sufficient statistic is complete or not for negative exponential distribution

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference, order-statistics

Let $X_1, X_2..., X_n$ follows iid negative exponential distribution with pdf

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\theta^2} \: e^{-\frac{(x-\theta)}{\theta^2}} \: \: I_{(x>\theta)} $$

I have to show whether the minimal sufficient statistic for this pdf is complete or not?
I have found that the minimal sufficient statistic is $T=\left( X_{(1)}, \sum_{i=1}^{n} (X_i - X_{(1)}) \right)$. If this minimal sufficient statistic is not complete then there exists a function $h(T)$ of the minimal sufficient statistic such that

$E_\theta [h(T)] =0$ for all $\theta>0$ where $h(T)$ is not identically zero.

Is this minimal sufficient complete or not? How can I find the function $h(T)$ of the minimal sufficient statistic?

Note that, $X_{(1)} $ is the first order statistic i.e., $min\{X_1,..X_n\}$. I have calculated the pdf of $X_{(1)}$. Let $Y= X_{(1)}$ then the pdf of $Y$ is given by,

$$ f(y) = \frac{n}{\theta^2} \: e^{-\frac{n(y-\theta)}{\theta^2}} \: \: I_{(y>\theta)} $$

I have also calculated

$$E(X)= \theta^2 + \theta $$ and $$E(Y) = \frac{\theta^2}{n} + \theta$$

Now, please help me to find out $h(T)$ for which $E_\theta[h(T)] = 0$ for all $\theta>0$ if the minimal sufficient statistic is not complete.

Comment: You have found $E\left[X_{(1)}\right]=\frac{\theta^2}{n} + \theta$; it could also be worth finding $E\left[ \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n} \left(X_i - X_{(1)}\right)\right]=(n-1)\theta^2$

Comment: @Henry right you are. Now, how can I combine them to get $h(T)$, so that $E[h(T)] = 0$, for all $\theta>0$. And$ h(T) $ is not identically zero.

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 kindly have a look at this problem.

Comment: Answered at https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/493394/119261.